# server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: linux

I am working on a Linux server which pop up's an error

> "server unexpecdly closed network connection"

but I am able to ping it. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is SSH protocol/port being allowed in the server's firewall config?
Is the SSH daemon running on the server?
do you have the correct login details (password/keys)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have bad luck, then the server is "pingable", but hangs (100% load in endless loop or whatever) and needs a reboot. Do you have any monitoring on the server?